# Rails Mongoid version error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Attempting to start the WEBrick server on a Rails 3 / Ruby 1.9.1 with Mongoid errors with:

> "MongoDB 1.4.0 not supported, please
>   upgrade to 1.6.0
>   (Mongoid::Errors::UnsupportedVersion)"

... but mongo --version:

> MongoDB shell version: 1.6.1

Anyone else seen this?

Pretty new to Ruby so apologies if I'm asking a stupid question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like it might have been a bit of a silly question and not one that'll trouble many people - check the mongoid.yml config file to make sure the server you're connecting to for your mongodb is the one you've upgraded. Quick switch to the right server and you're in business.